# Transition between vibronic states and the meaning of transition dipole moment

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, group-theory, spectroscopy

Let's say we have a molecule which belongs to $D_{3h}$ point group. The IRREPs of inital and final states are as follows $A'_{1}$, $E'$. Hence, the IRREP for the dipole moment has to be $E'$ so that the transition is allowed. Does this mean the external electric field has to have $x$ and $y$ components to interact with the molecule's dipole moment? Can we also say that the molecule's dipole moment vector has $x$ and $y$ components?